# Netsuite - Save search

Tags: report, netsuite

I have written a Netsuite Formula as below to take the difference between the number of days from the Inspection Scheduled Date and the Yard in date or Masho Receive date (Latest date from this).

Now this criteria is working fine but I want to categorize the results Number of days and group it in yards as below.

Yards/Days   1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8 & Above
Apex Nagoya
Apex Nagoya 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Blki.png)

My Criteria is

case when ({custrecord_cts_vc_yard_in_date}>{custrecord_cts_vc_masho_recd_date})then ({systemnotes.date}-{custrecord_cts_vc_yard_in_date})when ({custrecord_cts_vc_yard_in_date}<{custrecord_cts_vc_masho_recd_date})then ({systemnotes.date}-{custrecord_cts_vc_masho_recd_date}) when ({custrecord_cts_vc_yard_in_date}={custrecord_cts_vc_masho_recd_date})then ({systemnotes.date}-{custrecord_cts_vc_masho_recd_date})Else NULL End

Can some one help me to solve this.